# Ошибка с Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide, загрузка, запуск

Пишет вот это

> Возникла ошибка. Просмотрите файл протокола `C:\Users\(имя пользователя)\.metadata\.log`.

высвечивается это и не запускается, в файле `.log` пишет следующее:

```
!SESSION 2021-03-24 21:14:53.179 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.18.0.I20201202-1800
java.version=13.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ru
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-03-24 21:14:59.669
!MESSAGE Ошибка приложения
!STACK 1
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method 'void org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTable.addBinding(org.eclipse.jface.bindings.Binding)' the class loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @33a8c9c9 of the current class, org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/swt/util/BindingProcessingAddon, and the class loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @48d44b46 for the method's defining class, org/eclipse/e4/ui/bindings/internal/BindingTable, have different Class objects for the type org/eclipse/jface/bindings/Binding used in the signature (org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @33a8c9c9, parent loader 'platform'; org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTable is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @48d44b46, parent loader 'platform')
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBinding(BindingProcessingAddon.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBindingTable(BindingProcessingAddon.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBindingTables(BindingProcessingAddon.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.init(BindingProcessingAddon.java:96)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
```

Comment: Тут нет вашего кода, что собственно вы хотите от программы?

Comment: Чтобы она запускалась...

Comment: У вас программа не запускается или Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Программа Eclipse IDE, вообщем да, Eclipse IDE

Comment: Тогда вопрос не понятен, вы что собираетесь с ошибками Eclipse разбираться? Я сомневаюсь, что здесь есть эксперты этого уровня, которые дадут вам полноценный ответ, хотя кто знает...